# Login com Identity no MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Estou usando MVC 5 e Identity para o Login. Eu tenho uma classe Usuario e quero fazer o login com ela, usando as propriedades desta classe por exemplo a propriedade Registro(Usuario) no lugar da UserName(IdentityUser).

Tenho a Classe Usuario que herda do IdentityUser e controller é padrão do Identity

**Classe Usuario:**

```
 public class Usuario:IdentityUser
{
    public int FuncionarioID { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public string Registro { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

**Contoller/AccountController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Eu quero passar os dados do Usuario para registrar aqui:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

E para fazer login também:

```
//
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Registro, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Registro ou Senha Invalidas!");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Passando os dados da Classe Usuario aqui:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Registro, model.Password);
```

Comment: Você poderia colocar algum código do que você já tem implementado?

Comment: Inseri a Classe Usuario. Quero passar o Registro para o login ao invés do UserName do Identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dentro do seu arquivo `App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs`, modifique:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    ...
```

Para:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<Usuario>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<Usuario> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    ...
```

Assim como sua classe de `Usuario`, `ApplicationUser` também é derivada de `IdentityUser`.

O procedimento de login é o mesmo se você estivesse usando `ApplicationUser`:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(login, senha, lembrarme, shouldLockout: false);
```

`result` é um `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInStatus` (enum).

Comment: E como eu faria no controle para ele logar com os dados da Classe Usuario?

Comment: Vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: Cigano, estou usando Identity 1.0 que não tem a classe IdentityConfig.cs

Comment: @Janderson Preciso que você detalhe mais sua estrutura na pergunta para que minha resposta seja mais objetiva.

Comment: Editei a pergunta!

Comment: Pelo que vi, o 1.0 não dá a opção de estender o usuário. Não seria melhor atualizar seu ASP.NET Identity para a versão 2.0?

Comment: Pode ser, Como seria no 2.0?

Comment: Bom, minha resposta contempla bem o cenário do 2.0.

Comment: Fazendo aquelas alterações eu ja consigo fazer o registro e login?

Comment: @Janderson Consegue sim.